# Will an evap canister leak make the same noise as a cracked exhaust?

Tags: exhaust, leak, evap, code

Video of driving recorded with iPhone SE(5).

2002 Honda Accord, parked outdoors New England, 214,000 miles
Regular oil changes 1 owner before me, I got it around 150,000 great service records. Tran fluid, oil, coolant spark plugs, all replaced according to maintenance schedule.
It sounds like a boat!

https://youtu.be/bSe0MIcG05Y

The code is a P1457 evap canister leak.
I reset this code once last year after zip-tying the lines to the can. The codes came back on this year 2019. Any ideas to fix this? Duct tape? It’s a $220 dollar part but the electronics seem to be working.

Is this why my car sounds like it has a cracked exhaust?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but would suggest one has absolutely nothing to do with the other. The EVAP canister is pre-intake and the exhaust is ... well, the exhaust. It would be my approximation the EVAP system has nothing to do with the drone you're hearing.